# How do you grant access to resources across two separate Google Cloud Platform (GCP) projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Let's say you have two projects, IDs = `engine-project-1` and `storage-project-1`.

`engine-project-1` has a basic App Engine app that needs access to image files in a bucket in `storage-project-1`.  By default, `engine-project-1` is denied access to `storage-project-1`

How do you grant the app-engine-service role (`engine-project-1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`) in `engine-project-1` access to the storage role (`roles/storage.objectViewer`) in the `storage-project-1` account?

Answer (score 4):

### Use Case -- Allow an Outside App Engine App Access Build Status

For this example, the app engine app running in `${SOURCE_PROJECT_ID}` needs to access build status in `${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}`.

This can easily be done using the cloud shell activated for the project id = `${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}`

#### Grant a Role to An Outside Service Principle

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT \
--member=serviceAccount:${SOURCE_PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/cloudbuild.builds.viewer \
```

[More details on the solution here](https://tonym.us/gcp-managing-iam-access-control-across-projects-the-simpler-version.html#gcp-managing-iam-access-control-across-projects-the-simpler-version)