# Setting up service accounts between two projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have two GCP projects, one for continuous integration builds, and one for the team project.

**com-build :** 
contains

- triggers on code-repository
- docker images

service account : 1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
with roles service-account-administrator and cloudbuild-service-account

`g iam service-accounts get-iam-policy 1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com --project=com-build`

--> etag: ACAB

**com-project:** contains

- templates for VM
- VMs

service account : 5678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
with roles service-account-administrator and compute-instance-administrator

`g iam service-accounts get-iam-policy 5678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --project=com-project`

--> etag: ACAB –

I setup the cloudbuild.json file to update its container on code push, like this :

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
      "args": [
        "build",
        "-t",
        "****:latest",
        "."
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker",
      "args": [
        "push",
        "***:latest"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud",
      "args": [
        "compute",
        "instances",
        "update-container",
        "***",
        "--project=com-project",
        "--zone=somewhere"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following error :

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.update-container) The user does not
>   have access to service account
>   '5678-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'.  User:
>   '1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant
>   you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account

But both service-accounts have the role (I checked 20 times on iam settings)
am I missing something ?

Comment: @bhito - That is not correct. Project Editor / Owner is NOT required to access resources across projects.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the actual roles that are assigned using the `gcloud` command (and the commands that you used).

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for pointing it out, I got confused. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911980/how-do-you-grant-access-to-resources-across-two-separate-google-cloud-platform) has an answer to the similar question you have.

Comment: Neither service account have any IAM members assigned with permissions. When add permissions(roles) you can add them to the project or directly on the service account. You need the latter. You need to add `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` to the service account. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role

Comment: In the Google Cloud Console go to "IAM -> Service accounts". Near the top right-hand side is "SHOW INFO PANEL". Select the service account and then in the panel click "ADD MEMBER".

Comment: What does this command show (Edit your question): `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID`? Do this in both projects. I am only interested in the roles assigned to ` 1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Seems like `1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` service account misses the permission to update the container image. At `IAM & admin > Roles` search for `compute.images.update` (possibly the permission to execute `update-container`) to choose one of the available Roles that has this permission

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem :
1234@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com had to have access to Editor's role, in order to edit ressources in the other project

[image: rights must be Editor and service account admin]

Comment: Although it worked, it's always good practice to use least privilege access. Editor is a primitive role an has a lot of permissions that you don't need. A good practice is to use one permission related to what you want (`update-container`). Check for example, if `compute.images.update` attends your scenario